# Replace all occurrences except the first in Ruby. The regular expression spans multiple lines

Tags: ruby, regex, rubygems, rest-client

I am trying to down my last 3200 tweets in groups of 200(in multiple pages) using restclient gem.

In the process, I end up adding the following lines multiple times to my file:

```
</statuses>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
```

To get this right(as the XML parsing goes for a toss), after downloading the file, I want to replace all occurrences of the above string except the first.
I am trying the following:

```
 tweets_page = RestClient.get("#{GET_STATUSES_URL}&page=#{page_number}")
      message = <<-MSG
</statuses>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
MSG
      unless page_number == 1
       tweets_page.gsub!(message,"")
     end
```

What is wrong in the above? Is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be faster to download the whole bunch at once and split the body of your response by message and add it for the first entry.
Something like this, can't try it out so consider this just as an idea.

```
tweets_page = RestClient.get("#{GET_STATUSES_URL}").body
tweets = tweets_page.split(message)
tweets_page = tweets[0]+message+tweets[1..-1]
```

You could easily break them up in groups of 200 like that also

If you want to do it with a gsub on the whole text you could use the following

```
tweets_page = <<-MSG
first
</statuses>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
second
</statuses>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
rest
MSG

message = <<-MSG
</statuses>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
MSG

new_str = tweets_page.gsub message do |match|
  if defined? @first
    ""
  else
    @first = true
    message
  end
end

p new_str
```

gives

```
type=\"array\">\nrest\n"
"first\n</statuses>\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<statuses type=\"array\">\nsecond\nrest\n"
```

Comment: Why is that? I want to make the changes to tweet_page, right? Anyway, that doesn't work.

Comment: I think, it would make sense to download the whole page and then replace all matches except the first. I think, the mistake was that I was doing writing to the file and the replacement in the same loop

Comment: if tweets_page.gsub(message,"") is the last line of a method it will return the gsubbed version, but you'r right, the ! should work also. What do you get as result ?

Comment: that approach would also work, i just figured it would be simpler with the split method, next time publishing more of your code, that makes it easier to help

Comment: There is a problem in downloading the whole thing at once as twitter might limit downloading at one go. I need to replace all occurrences except the first. How do I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12463/discussion-between-yahoo-me-and-peter)